# Upload files to Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, dropzone.js

I am using a DropzoneJS Plugin in my Django project. I want to upload files to the database (The problem is that I am uploading blank file objects without a file attached).

[image]

[image]

These are the models:

```
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = 'Files'

    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.file

    def __str__(self):
      return "{file}".format(file=self.file)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse("Assignments:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

class Assignment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    created = models.DateField(default=date.today, null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(default = date.today, null=True)

    files = models.ManyToManyField(File, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = 'Assignments'

    def __str__(self):
      return "{name}".format(name=self.name)
```

This is my view for posting:

```
@login_required
def teacher_assignment_add_files(request, assignment_id):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    thefile = request.FILES.get('file-assignment')
    file = File(file=thefile)
    file.save()


    assignment = Assignment(id=assignment_id)
    assignment.files.add(file.id)
    return redirect('teacher-detail-assignment', id = assignment_id)
```

I have tried:

```
thefile = request.Files['file-assignment']
```

This donsen't even create an object

The HTML form to create a file:

```
<form class="dropzone" action="{% url 'teacher_assignment_add_file' OBJECTID %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="fallback">
 <input type="submit" type="file" name="file-assignment" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: pls show your javascript code

Comment: I use a plugin called DropzoneJS - https://www.dropzonejs.com